# Undefined index when trying to get information from a 2nd page

Tags: php, session

I use my session with sql Information but I get a really weird error.
I have 2 pages at the moment. Now I have this in my 1st page:

```
while ($thread = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {

    echo"<div id='question'<h2>
             {$thread['title']}</br>
                 </h2>
                 <p style='font-size:16; text-align:left;'>
                 {$thread['description']}
                 </p>
                 <center>
                 <a href=profile.php?thread_username={$thread['username']}> {$thread['username']}</a></br>
                 {$thread['date_made']} </center></div>";
    $_SESSION['profileuser']=$thread['username'];
}
```

So when you click the link, `$_SESSION['profileuser']` will get the thread username.

Here's what I have in my 2nd page:

```
$profileusername = $mysqli2->real_escape_string($_SESSION['profileuser']);
```

The error I get is:

*Undefined index*

My other sessions work perfectly but this probably just wont do.

**Of course I have session_start(); on every page...**

When I press this button(on the 2nd page) it gives me the error:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 
            $about = $_POST['about'];
            $sql_result2 = $mysqli->query("update account_information SET about='".$about."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'");
            $edit=false;

        }
```

**EDIT:** I fixed it.

Comment: here goes a dozen answers "you have to start a session on every page" but not a single closevote. Rep is so sweet.

Comment: @YourCommonSense My session does start on every page...
I have session_start(); on every page

Comment: Do a `print_r($_SESSION)` to see if any data is submitted

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION) what does it returns

Comment: @Reeno Array ( [username] => myusername [idcheck] => 2 )

Comment: Why `username` and not `profileuser`? Are you assigning it wrong on the first page?

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui ["username"]=> string(4) "myusername" ["idcheck"]=> string(1) "2"

Comment: @Reeno I take the row username. I call the session:"profileuser"

Comment: @loko: But when print_r($_SESSION) returns `Array ( [username] => myusername [idcheck] => 2 )`, the variable name in the session is `username` and not `profileuser`. Are mixing up something there?

Comment: BTW it only gives me the error when I press the button on the 2nd page. See my edit.

Comment: @Reeno No I actually now think the problem isn't the session.

Comment: In the edit you use `$_SESSION["username"]`. Are you sure you always choose the correct array indices?

Comment: @Reeno Srry that's a different session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this code to your second page:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$var=$_SESSION['profileuser'];
if(empty($var))
{
die("Session variable is empty");
}
?>
```

it will help you to know the root of problem

Answer (score 0):

Change:

$profileusername = $mysqli2->real_escape_string($_SESSION['profileuser']);

To:

$profileusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['profileuser']);